# how to add elements with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

What is the best practice working with Jetback Compose ?

Should I make every element of my UI as an individual @composable function and then call it under a @Composble column function as shown in code number 1. or make all elements under one @composable column function as shown in code number 2?

note that in all cases the outcome is sameler!

Code 1

```
@Composable
fun LauncherAa() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Black).fillMaxHeight(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {

        BoxScopeImage()
        BoxScopeText1()
        BoxScopeText2()
    }
}

@Composable
fun BoxScopeImage(){
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground), contentDescription = null )
}
@Composable
fun BoxScopeText1(){
    Text(text = "Welcome to android World", color = Color.White, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)}
@Composable
fun BoxScopeText2(){
    Text(text = "Click Anywhere to Start",color = Color.White, modifier = Modifier)
}
```

Code 2

```
@Composable
fun LauncherAa() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Black).fillMaxHeight().weight(1f),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {

        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground), contentDescription = null )
        Text(text = "Welcome to World", color = Color.White, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        Text(text = "Click Anywhere to Start",color = Color.White, modifier = Modifier)
    }
}
```

Working with Compose Using Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Code 2 is a better approach, you shouldn't make a different composable for a single view.
A composable should contain a significant part of your screen.
For example you would create a composable function for a TopAppBar then a composable for the main screen and at last a function for the BottomNavigation and call all these three functions from a MainScreen function which would contain a column scope to display all these components.

Answer (score 0):

It depends mostly on you and your teammates if you have some. Like you said, both do the same, so it comes down to your preference. Generally, I would suggest creating a composable function in 2 cases:

- something you will reuse on multiple places - for example `Button` themed for your app
- some logical unit that wraps many simple composables - for example, you can have `EmptyContent`, `LoadingContent` and `LoadedContent` composables that will be called conditionally from your `Screen` composable.

So, in your example, I definitely prefer the second variant.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you go with the 2nd option if you are using the pre-defined components provided already, the 1st option is useful only when you want to club a group of components together for the re-usability of that component in your current project or another project.

**Option 1 use case**:

```
@Composable
fun RoundedChip(
    text: String,
    textColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
    textStyle: TextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.copy(color = textColor),
    shape: Shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
) {
    androidx.compose.material3.Card(
        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center),
        shape = shape,
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(backgroundColor)
    ) {
        androidx.compose.material3.Text(
            text = text,
            style = textStyle,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 9.dp, vertical = 0.dp)
                .offset(y = (-2).dp),
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            softWrap = true,
            maxLines = 1,
        )
    }
}
```

Now I can use the Rounded Chip anywhere I need it in my project, I need on some other project i can just copy paste it so i guess this helps.

**Option 2 use case:**
Just your own code with a different name :)

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Black).fillMaxHeight().weight(1f),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {

        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground), contentDescription = null )
        Text(text = "Welcome to World", color = Color.White, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        Text(text = "Click Anywhere to Start",color = Color.White, modifier = Modifier)
    }
}
```

Hope this helped you @aboulfadl

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see from the angle of your examples but when you get used to use second approach you might have hard time when your codebase is largen. Even when you have 300-500 lines of compose codebase which is not that large, it might be a torture to find the exact composable that you might want to change. So, I would go with first one EXCEPT for the very small projects.

Also you must keep in mind to [hoist](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting) your state when using first approach.